# C Programming: How to prevent printf statement from printing out new line values?

Tags: c, printf, scanf, newline

My code works fine, except for one line which keeps printing out the data that supposed to be for the next line only.

The output is supposed to look something like this:

```
Address Details
Street number: 100
Street name: Bedrock
Apartment: 14
Postal code: Z8Z 7R7
City: Markham
```

Instead my output is this:

```
Address Details
Street number: 100
Street name: Bedrock
Apartment: 14
Postal code: Z8Z 7R7Markham
City: Markham
```

As you can see `Markham` is printed along the same line of postal code.
Below are the potential files which might have caused this error. All help is much appreciated!

**a1ms4.c file:**

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>

// This source file needs to "know about" the structures you declared
// in the header file before referring to those new types:
// HINT: put the header file name in double quotes so the compiler knows
//       to look for it in the same directory/folder as this source file
// #include your contacts header file on the next line:
#include "contacts.h"


int main(void)
{
    // Declare variables here:

    // Create a variable of type Contact and call it something self-describing like "contact"
    // - HINT: Be sure to initialize the values to 0 and empty C strings
    struct Contact contact = {
        { "", "", "" },
        {0," ", 0, " ", " "},
        { "", "", "" }
    };


    // Display the title
    printf("Contact Management System\n");
    printf("-------------------------\n");



    // Call the Contact function getName to store the values for the Name member
    getName(&contact.name);


    // Call the Contact function getAddress to store the values for the Address member
    getAddress(&contact.address);


    // Call the Contact function getNumbers to store the values for the Numbers member
    getNumbers(&contact.numbers);



    // Display Contact summary details

    printf("\nContact Details\n");
    printf("---------------\n");
    printf("Name Details\n");
    printf("First name: %s", contact.name.firstName);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Middle initial(s): %s", contact.name.middleInitial);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Last name: %s", contact.name.lastName);
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Address Details\n");
    printf("Street number: %d", contact.address.streetNumber);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Street name: %s", contact.address.street);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Apartment: %d", contact.address.apartmentNumber);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Postal code: %s", contact.address.postalCode);
    printf("\n");
    printf("City: %s", contact.address.city);
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Phone Numbers:");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Cell phone number: %s", contact.numbers.cell);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Home phone number: %s", contact.numbers.home);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Business phone number: %s", contact.numbers.business);
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");






    // Display Completion Message
    printf("Structure test for Contact using functions done!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**contacts.c file**

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>

// This source file needs to "know about" the structures you declared
// in the header file before referring to those new types:
// HINT: put the header file name in double quotes so the compiler knows
//       to look for it in the same directory/folder as this source file
// #include your contacts header file on the next line:
#include "contacts.h"

// Get and store from standard input the values for Name
// Put your code here that defines the Contact getName function:
void getName(struct Name * name) {
    //Variable/Struct declaration:
    char notify;

    // Contact Name Input:
    printf("Please enter the contact's first name: ");
    scanf("%30s", name->firstName);

    //Prompts the user to see if they want to enter a middle name using y, yes or n, no.
    printf("Do you want to enter a middle initial(s)? (y or n): ");
    scanf("%s", &notify);

    if (notify == 'y' || notify == 'Y')
    {
        printf("Please enter the contact's middle initial(s): ");
        scanf("%6s", name->middleInitial);
    }

    printf("Please enter the contact's last name: ");
    scanf("%30s", name->lastName);
}


// Get and store from standard input the values for Address
// Put your code here that defines the Contact getAddress function:
void getAddress(struct Address * address) {
    //Variable/Structure declaration: 
    char notify;

    // Contact Address Input:
    printf("Please enter the contact's street number: ");
    scanf("%d",& (address->streetNumber));

    printf("Please enter the contact's street name: ");
    scanf("%40s", address->street);

    //Prompts the user to see if they want to enter an apartment number using yes, or no.
    printf("Do you want to enter an apartment number? (y or n): ");
    scanf("%s", &notify);

    if (notify == 'y' || notify == 'Y')
    {
        printf("Please enter the contact's apartment number: ");
        scanf("%d",& (address->apartmentNumber));
    }

    printf("Please enter the contact's postal code: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]", address->postalCode);

    printf("Please enter the contact's city: ");
    scanf(" %40s", address->city);

}


// Get and store from standard input the values for Numbers
// Put your code here that defines the Contact getNumbers function:
void getNumbers(struct Numbers *numbers) {
    //Variable/Structure declaration:
    char notify;

    // Contact Numbers Input:
    printf("Do you want to enter a cell phone number? (y or n): "); //Prompt the user to see if they want to enter a cellphone.
    scanf(" %s", &notify);

    if (notify == 'y' || notify == 'Y')
    {
        printf("Please enter the contact's cell phone number: ");
        scanf("%20s", numbers->cell);
    }

    printf("Do you want to enter a home phone number? (y or n): ");
    scanf(" %s", &notify);

    if (notify == 'y' || notify == 'Y')
    {
        printf("Please enter the contact's home phone number: ");
        scanf("%20s", numbers->home);
    }

    printf("Do you want to enter a business phone number? (y or n): ");
    scanf(" %s", &notify);

    if (notify == 'y' || notify == 'Y')
    {
        printf("Please enter the contact's business phone number: ");
        scanf("%20s", numbers->business);
    }
}
```

**contacts.h**

```
// Structure type Name declaration (Milestone 1)
struct Name {
    char firstName[31];
    char middleInitial[7];
    char lastName[36];
};

// Structure type Address declaration 
// Place your code here... (from Milestone 1)
struct Address {
    int streetNumber;
    char street[40];
    int apartmentNumber;
    char postalCode[7];
    char city[40];
};


// Structure type Numbers declaration
// Place your code here... (from Milestone 1)
struct Numbers {
    char cell[20], home[20], business[20];
};
```

Comment: `notify` is of type `char`. Why are you doing this: `scanf("%s", &notify)`?

Comment: @Joe Kennedy It seems that the reason of the problem is memory overlapping for character arrays produced by entered strings..

Comment: What is `struct Contact` and what is `struct Address`? (show us `contacts.h`)

Comment: `[help-me]` Please provide the definition of the `Address` structure. Likely, you do not allocate enough characters for `postalCode`. Is it `char postalCode[7]`?

Comment: notify is just a char variable that asks them whether or not they want to provide optional information like apartment number.

Comment: Yes. postalCode is a char allocated to fit 7 characters.

Comment: As far as I know contacts.h has no additional problems that could interfere. Just structure declarations, the one possible connection could the address structure I have: - which has char postalCode[7]

Comment: i'm guessing since the structure data is missing. but if you allocate 7 `char`s for the postal code, then you dont have a space for the null terminator. you print the postal code by `%s` which means it will print the entire array and will continue on to the first `\0` which is set for the next argument. to solve this allocate 8 `char`s and set a null terminator on the last byte after you recieved the postal code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should have a null terminator on the end of the postal code:

```
struct Address {
    int streetNumber;
    char street[40];
    int apartmentNumber;
    char postalCode[8];// add space for the null terminator
    char city[40];
};

printf("Please enter the contact's postal code: ");
scanf(" %[^\n]", address->postalCode);
address->postalCode[7] = '\0'; // add a null terminator
```

this should be enough to solve the issue

Comment: yes, haha that was the problem. Can't believe it was something so simple!

Comment: glad i can help :)